# SVG UIBarbuttons are becoming big

Tags: ios, swift, svg, uibarbuttonitem

Im using SVG images by converting them into PDF format. But sometimes, those `barbutton` items are becoming very big. Maximum of times am facing this issue is while using `UIAlertController` (Ex: Showing an alert, showing action sheet)

Here is the code i use to assign SVG as `UIBarButton`s

```
    let search:UIButton = Utilities.getButton(forTitle: "", buttonType: .custom, image: IMAGE_SEARCH_SVG);
    search.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSearchAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    search.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: H20, height: H20)
    let searchBarBtnItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: search)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  =  searchBarBtnItem
```

[u can see search icon on the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fQ3i.png)

[on showing UIAlertAction,the search icon became big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdnER.png)

Can someone help me in fixing this.

Comment: add original template also

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have tried that too.But no luck :(